# Scale UIImageView relatively

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview, scale

I've got two UIImageViews, I've managed to merge and save them. But I want the overlaying image to scale and position relatively with the scale of the chosen image. So that the UIImageView that you see on the screen looks the same as the UIImageView which it saves.

```
- (UIImage *)combineImages{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(theimageView.image.size.width,theimageView.image.size.height));

// Draw image1
[theimageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, theimageView.image.size.width,theimageView.image.size.height)];

// Draw image2
[Birdie.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(Birdie.center.x, Birdie.center.y, (theimageView.image.size.width / 2), (theimageView.image.size.height / 2))];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return resultingImage;
```

}

theImageView and Birdie are the two UIImageViews.
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: please clear it little more. Do you wish to have same size of imageView as of baseImageView on which you are adding new one? suppose one(baseImageView) has width of 20 and other has 10. combined makes 30 but you want to display it in 20. is it so?

Comment: I have two UIImageViews, the first one is like the background. You have to choose it yourself. This one can be every size. The second UIImageView is just a standard image with a fixed size. You can move the second one over the screen, it overlays the background. This image is displayed in a UIImageView, but scaled down so it fits the screen. You can drag the second image over it and I want that the saved image has the size of the background (which is chosen), and that the second image stands on the same place as the view. Sounds complicated but it's like some of the 'hairdress' apps etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
  - (UIImage *)combineImages{



    // Draw image1
    [theimageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, theimageView.image.size.width,theimageView.image.size.height)];

    // Draw image2
    [Birdie.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(Birdie.frame.origin.x, Birdie.frame.origin.y, Birdie.frame.size.width, Birdie.frame.size.height)];
    //have you added Birdie over theimageView if not than do this. If your size is already set as you want then there is no need for above two lines of drawInRect.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theimageView.bounds.size);
    [theimageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I save the image it doesn't has the same size as the original UIImageView which is chose (theimageView), and the second chosen image from Birdie isn't added. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Tim, where are you adding Birdie? on originalImageview or on self.view?In my opinion you should put Birdie on originalImageview so that you will not need the first two lines of drawRect:. if you see I have commented something there. Please ans and try this approach.

Comment: How do you mean originalImageview or self.view? I'm sorry but I'm kind of a rookie, so I don't understand the whole thing. You mean where I've putten the Birdie inside the interface builder or..? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: My question was which view is superview of birdie? please see in xib also please try with commenting first two line of code(where we are calling drawRect method.

Comment: It doesn't has a superview as far as I know, I don't know where to find this in de xib exactly. Is it easier if I send you the whole code, from the .h and the .m? Or maybe an image from the xib? I've got a few buttons, each button will call an other image on the UIImageView called Birdie. This UIImageView is overlaying theimageView, and I want the saved image to match the screen. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: so you are adding birdie on theimageView? or is it on self.view?(from xib, in heirarcy of ui elements you can see where birdie lies under which element in that tree and what is that element?

Comment: I want the image which's saved to have the Birdie on theimageView, but I really couldn't find the Hierarchy. I do know that I haven't grouped it or anything, so I think it is self.view. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Tim then for once try with [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
rather than earlier one. Please inform me soon abt the outcome. Thanks

Comment: It worked, but the quality is rather bad and it has a white border because the size of the UIImageView doesn't adapt to the size of the chosen image. Is there something for this? Thank you really much!

Comment: Tim, what we are doing here is we are saving layer of self.view as image. So if the self.view is a bit larger than your theimageView then this border may come.(its give's image what we have on self.view). One thing you can do is. write [Birdie removeFromSuperView]; [theimageView addSubView:Birdie];(please set frame as need) [this will add birdie on theimageView if its somewhere else] then, write [theimageView.layer  renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; rather than changed one. try it.it may work. thanks

Comment: Thank you I will try that, but do you know how to get better quality ? And it crashes the second time I save an image. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Does it shows any crash log. Please post it if it does so that we can resolve the matter. Tim when you try the recent approach that we discussed then may be quality will be as desired. But if not then we will try something more. Thanks

Comment: It's really weird because the quality is really bad.. And the weird thing is that it crashes directly when saving the image when I test it on my iPhone, it shows: 
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3 (8F190)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found). And on the simulator it only says invalid context and throwing instance of NSexception. I also don't know where to put the [theimageView addSubView:Birdie] and [Birdie removeFromSuperView];Thanks in advanced!

Comment: put these lines in viewDidLoad. Please first put [Birdie removeFromSuperView]; then other line.

Comment: I get the error: UIImageView may not respond to -removeFromSuperView and UIImageView may not respond to -addSubView: Thanks in advanced!